# How to add touch button in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, game-development, flame

I need to add touch button, when I touch the button it needs to do a task, when I release the button it need to stop doing the task.

```
@override
  voidonTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    isTapped=true;
    super.onTapDown(event);
  }
```

I have used Tap Events but I need my button to do task on continuous touching, when I release it needs to stop doing tasks, How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To do something continuously, you need to override both `tapUp` and `tapDown`, and keep track of the state:

```dart
class MyButton extends PositionComponent with TapCallbacks {
  bool isTapping = false;

  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    isTapping = true;
  }

  void onTapUp(TapUpEvent event) {
    isTapping = false;
  }
}
```

Then you can override your `update` method to do something every tick given the value of that variable:

```
@override
void update(double dt) {
  if (isTapping) {
    // something * dt
  }
}
```